# How does Python determine whether to represent a number using scientific notation or not?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, floating-point, repr

Here are some numbers entered in the Python console, and the resulting representations:

```
>>> 1
1
>>> 1.234
1.234
>>> 1.234e5
123400.0
>>> 1.234e15
1234000000000000.0
>>> 1.234e25
1.234e+25
```

... and here's what happens when the same numbers are printed:

```
>>> print 1
1
>>> print 1.234
1.234
>>> print 1.234e5
123400.0
>>> print 1.234e15
1.234e+15  # different!
>>> print 1.234e25
1.234e+25
```

How does Python decide which representation to use? Why is it different with and without `print` for some numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only floating point numbers are represented using scientific notation in Python; integers are always represented as-is.

How a floating point number is represented in Python 2.7 depends on whether it's represented using [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr) (for instance, directly in the console or as a member of a collection) or [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) (e.g. with the `print` statement).

With `repr()`, floating point numbers are represented using scientific notation if they are either less than `0.0001` (`1e-4`) or at least `1e16`:

```
>>> 1e-4
0.0001
>>> 0.00009999
9.999e-05
>>> 1e16-2
9999999999999998.0
>>> 10000000000000000.0
1e+16
```

With `str()`, the upper limit is approximately `1e11`:

```
>>> print 1e11-1
99999999999.0
>>> print 100000000000.0
1e+11
```

Note: in Python 3, `str()` now represents floating point numbers in the same way as `repr()`.

Answer (score 2):

Numeric values are just stored as values. The `__repr__` output may change based on the implementation and type of number. You need to format the string representation of a number.

Example:

```
>>> type(1e3) is type(1000.0) # float
True
>>> type(1e3) is type(1000)  # int
False
```

When you format a string, you can use `%g`/`{:g}` to have it automatically determine the most readable format. Use `%e`/`{:e}` for explicit scientific notation.

```
>>> x = 1234567
>>> "{:.2e}".format(x)
1.23e+06
```

Comment: –1  using identity comparisons of numbers brings all kind of irrelevant implementation details into the mix

Comment: @wim not really the point, but I understand. It was only meant to show that scientific notation IS still a number. It's not like a seperate type. I will change it to `type`, though.